# Controlling sewing machine motor speed with input from a pressure transducer

Tags: motor-controller

I would like to control the speed of a sewing machine with the output from a pressure transducer. The sewing machine motor is 230VAC (50Hz)  universal motor.  I am going to use an  MPS20N0040D-D transducer receiving pressurized air from a Presair foot actuator.

The current controller is an older carbon pile resistor type placed in between the live (hot) input of the AC mains and the motor. I would like to replace this with a controller that takes the signal that is produced by the transducer and uses it to trigger motor speed control circuitry. When the pressure produced by Presair foot activator rises the speed of the motor should rise. I understand that I may need to amplify the signal from the transducer before passing it to another circuit and know how to do this.

I am unsure about best way to approach the next stage, using the signal from the transducer in a way that allows it to govern change in the motor's speed and integrating this circuitry to replace the old controller.

Comment: Have you considered using a lamp dimmer switch and seeing if that can provide the functionality without the foot interface? Beware: AC mains voltages are lethal. *Any suggestions are welcome* <-- also be aware that this is basically asking for opinions and the site has rules about this: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: You can buy a sewing machine pedal (potentiometer based) with a built-in speed controller for the cost of a cheap lunch downtown. Using a pressure sensor would require  either a much more complex controller with galvanic isolation on the control signal or running the pressure sensor, signal conditioning etc. at mains potential. Are you up for that?

Comment: I am [working on a sewing machine motor speed control](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/motorcontrol-toc) of my own.  Because I am a chicken, all of the control circuitry is a low voltage.  An Arduino reads a Hall effect pedal and generates a PWM signal to control the speed of the motor.  There will be a tachometer feedback with PID to keep the speed steady.  The motor itself is driven by rectified DC, with an isolated gate driver between the high and low voltage halves.

Comment: The point being to maintain a steady and easily controllable low speed on a machine that was designed to be **fast.**  I use it to sew leather, but it is too fast for me. The other thing is that such vintage machines with big balance wheels tend to keep stitching when you let off the pedal at high speed - that makes it hard to stop on the right spot.

Comment: If you are trying to replace the controller on a machine that originally had a motor, then you might want to look at the [commercially available motors and controllers.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/sewingmachinemotor) If you don't need PID control and your machine has a small balance wheel then wiring such a controller to your existing motor will be simpler and cheaper.  You can adjust the controllers to reduce the maximum speed if you need to.

Comment: The air pressure foot pedal you linked to doesn't mention the pressure range that it generates.  I'm pretty sure it will exceed the limits of the pressure sensor you referred to, though, since the sensor is made for low pressure (maximum 0.8PSI.)

Comment: You would need to amplify the output to make it more usable, then map the amplified signal to PWM proportions.  That could be done all analog, but more common would be to digitize the amplified signal and useva microcontroller to generate the PWM.

Comment: It would be easier to find a pressure sensor with a 0-5V output over a range that matches the pressure range of the pedal - but first you have to find out how much pressure the pedal generates.

Comment: @JRE  thanks for all your suggestions may end up using a pressure sensor  with a bigger range however the sensor I have is rated up to 40kpa or close to 5.8 psi according to the data sheet.  Using a micro controller is now coming under serious consideration.  .